# working with some components I see index classes defined

Tags: css, vuejs2

In my Laravel 5.8 / vuejs 2.6 app working with some components (vue-easy-slider in my case) I see that they have 
classes defined with somer index like :

```
[data-v-6ce668ac]
```

So to change this class I have to set definition :

```
<style lang="scss">
    .slider-icon-left[data-v-6ce668ac] {
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        border-left: 3px solid $navigation-color !important;
        border-bottom: 3px solid $navigation-color !important;
    }
```

What is data-v-6ce668ac here ? Can I set in style block?
It looks like temporary index... Would it be the same in the next session ?

Comment: Could you add the resulting HTML to your question? That might make it easier to help.

Answer (score 1):

Its dynamic generated during code execution so don't target with [data-v-6ce668ac]

Instead you can target with [class^=slider-icon-left],

```
[class^=slider-icon-left]{
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   border-left: 3px solid $navigation-color !important;
   border-bottom: 3px solid $navigation-color !important;
}
```

Comment: construction 
[class^=slider-icon-left]{ ...
does not work for me
Please, give a link when such consctruction is described, that is something new for me.
Maybe I had to mention, that my code above was in vue file.

Comment: working example https://codepen.io/Partha_Sarathy/pen/PooaxKb

Comment: That does not work for me. Can issue be that I have lang="scss" in vue file and it works differently ?